# Finite sigma-additive measure is of bounded variation

Tags: measure-theory

I came across a proposition, which doesn't seem obvious, but I'm curious about whether it is actually true:

**Proposition:**  If $\mu$ is a  sigma-additive signed measure (i.e. set function) which is finite, then it is of bounded variation.

Comment: Can you do the case where $\mu$ is a positive measure?  Why would that help in the problem you have?